# Taking the form of robots I beat

Tags: robots

I am creating a story where the protagonist is able to take the form of robots and using them. Its just like possessing them, he is able to move the robots and exploit every ability they had.

Now one thing is that in order to do so, the protagonist has to beat them first.

Image a D&D fight. If you win the fight against the robot, you are able to move the robot instead. In case the robot dies/is destroyed, you play with your normal character.

But there are a lot of ambiguities to this story. First of all, who is the main protagonist? Can he be human or something else? Maybe a robot, an android etc?

And how can he take the form after he beats them? I mean, arent they destroyed after he beats them?

Maybe he induces damage long enough in order to insert a virus that overrides their functions?

If that is true, he cannot be an operator in physical form, inhabiting them.

Maybe he does enough damage in order to expose an opening to the human operator, taking him out and becoming the operator himself? If that were true, he would also be exposed to enemy attacks.

So as you can see, I have a lot of "holes" creating this kind of story.
Anyone can give me some hints?

Comment: You have asked for fixing holes in plot. This is outside the scope of worldbuilding. It's very hard to have a Q&A format for plot holes because it is essentially a game-tree of if-this-then-that-ooh-how-about-the-other-thing. These make for poor questions on Stack Exchange generally.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of ideas come to mind. To start, let's look at the thin line between robot and human.

[Armitage III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armitage_III) immediately comes to mind. The protagonist, Naomi Armitage is a Third, a type of robot that feels and thinks like a human, if with some badassery tossed into the mix. It would allow her to 'hack' into robots and control them, though defeating them first isn't always a requirement. It would be a pretty badass sight to see this type of protagonist standing in front of an army of robots they control, daring all challengers to 'have at'.

Another option is Pluto, also from Armitage. Though he is also a Third, he is very different. He's more the plotter, behind the scenes. He strikes me as the type to hack into the robots while someone else (another robot perhaps) is fighting them.

It could also be there are simply hackers in your world, and that all robots are programmed to attack the one trying to hack them. It could be that there is a signal scrambler that disables any frequencies but one, and the only way to test that is to get in close and test them one by one. This might well tip off the robot, and cause its core programming (to remain faithful and subservient to its owner, for example) to kick in and attack the hacker. It would take someone with balls of steel to try their hand at it, and someone that is both a genius (to be a hacker in the first place) and a quick thinker (to hack while under attack), but it could make for an interesting character.

It could also be that there are no wireless options, that there's only a hard port that the hacker has to access. In order to do so, you must disable to robot to begin with. This would take cunning and planning, given you want to capture the robot and not destroy it. It could also be that not every robot type has this port in the same location, or perhaps has 'dummy ports' to trap potential hackers and either self-destruct (military grade robots) or format its own harddrive to make it all but useless.